# Javascript function in separate file is not working in index.html with onclick element

Tags: javascript, html, button

I've got an issue that should work, but simply won't. I've got index.html and app.js in the same directory, and my html element looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Hi</h1>
        <button onclick="print_words()">Link Google Ads Account</button>
        <button onclick="console.log('index')">Index</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
function print_words() {
    console.log("App");
}
```

when I run this with "python -m http.server 4200" and click the button, I get the following error:

```
(index):6 Uncaught ReferenceError: print_words is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

The index button works as expected.
This is a ridiculously simple script that should work, but doesn't. Any suggestions? Maybe it has to do with the python server? Idk

I tried putting it in a body, tried putting it in the header, tried console.log() function within the onclick element, which worked as expected.

Comment: Have you checked your browser debug tools to see if the `app.js` file was successfully loaded?

Comment: Try to include your script in the end of HTML.

Comment: @TheNikCD in this case that would make no difference at all.

Comment: Try to add  `defer` or `async` to your script: `<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" defer></script>` This will ensure that the script is loaded after the HTML content is parsed, which can sometimes cause issues with functions not being defined.